# Matplotlib double bar chart: Bars not properly drawn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to plot two different data columns of a frame ("n" and "m") for each data set as two differently colored bars next to each other.

```
def graphPlot(data, size=None):
    pos = arange(len(data))+.5    # the bar centers on the y axis
    figure(figsize=size)
    xscale("log")
    barh(pos, data["n"], align='center', height=0.25, color="darkgrey")    
    barh(pos - 0.25, data["m"], align='center', height=0.25, color="lightblue")    
    yticks(pos, data["graph"])
    xlabel("")
    grid(True)
```

But it turns out like this:

[image]

Why are the bars not properly drawn? Are my position values wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `xscale("log")` call causing the problems. You need the plots to be scaled so instead pass `log=True` to the `barh` calls:

```
def graphPlot(data, size=None):
    pos = arange(len(data))+.5    # the bar centers on the y axis
    figure(figsize=size)
    #xscale("log")
    barh(pos, data["n"], align='center', height=0.25, color="darkgrey", log=True)    
    barh(pos - 0.25, data["m"], align='center', height=0.25, color="lightblue", log=True)    
    yticks(pos, data["graph"])
    xlabel("")
    grid(True)
```

An alternative is to use a [pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) to hold your data and then simply call `df[['ser1', 'ser2']].plot(kind='barh', logx=True)`.